Do tomato seeds release all their flavours if fried or boiled?
The centre of the tomato and seeds carry a lot of intense flavours, so I’m wondering if you cook tomatoes say by frying or making a stew, will the acidic and other flavours come out and get released into the frying oil and stew liquid? Then, would it be fine to filter the cooked seeds out without any loss of flavour?
I imagine all that remains within the seed AFTER cooking is the shell itself and the fiber in it but not the things that give tomatoes their many flavours.

Never noticed tomato seeds to actually have much of a flavour, and if anything not a pleasant one. It's the pulp that's tasty.
